# regex ruby valid for letters-digits and digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have 2 regexps in ruby. The first regex is for letters and digits something like:

```
letter_digits = /^([0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/
```

With this regex if I write only digits `564521` does not match!

However I have this regex for only digits:

```
only_digits = /^([0-9])*$/
```

But with this regex if I write `s45xo` does not match!

I need only **1 regex valid** for both **letters/digits** and **digits**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `letter_digits = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/`

Your first regexp `/^([0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/` says that there should be digits (0 or more), then letter (1), then digits or letters (0 or more).

My advise is to read something about regexp, for example [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Comment: No because "this shouldn't\nmatch" =~ /^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/

Comment: That string shouldn't match the regex.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest regex is:

```
/\A[a-z\d]*\Z/i
```